# Difference between `null` and `no output`

Tags: json, null, jq, is-empty

I've encountered some difference between `null` and `nothing`, can somebody explain it? As in most languages `null` is considered/used to represent nothing.

The `select` is documented to return no output. And adding(ie. `+`) `null` to X yields X. Now consider these demonstrative examples(takes no  input):

1. adding *nothing*

here we have empty object, which we update with nothing:

```
{} | . |= . + ({} | select (.foo == 123))
```

which results in

```
null
```

2. adding *null*

same template but with alternative operator to substitute *nothing* to *null*:

```
{} | . |= . + ({} | select (.foo == 123)//null)
```

which results in

```
{}
```

Can someone explain the difference `nothing` vs `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is just a regular JSON value; and conceptually, it is totally different from the absence of a value, i.e, what you termed *nothing*. Take a look at these for example (`empty` is a filter that returns nothing):

```
$ jq -n '[null] | length'
1
$ jq -n '[empty] | length'
0
```

That `{} + null` returns `{}` back, and that `{} | . |= empty` does exactly what `del(.)` does are merely design choices.

Comment: thanks. I never had time to read manual from top to bottom and this leaves me with this basic misunderstandings. Thanks!